# paypal IPN script called on and off - maybe missing IP addresses for firewall

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, firewall-access

The past few days some transactions are failing in the sense that the IPN script is not being called to complete and verify
the transaction.

Some go thru and some do not.

Either there is something wrong at PayPal's backend or I don't have all the IP addresses listed in the Firewall to
allow access to the server.

What exactly is the IP Range or list of ip addresses used by the Instant Notification Script.

I'm using the product Web Payments Standard.

Thanks for any help you can give.

regards
David j.

Comment: Issue resolved. Customer's IPN was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92 gives the current list of IP addresses. They suggest you subscribe to the page so you'll get an email when the list is updated - you have to have a Paypal Developer account for that, though.